# FLAC metadata analytics software

Tags: metadata, flac

I have a large music library in FLAC files, organized thanks to EasyTag.

I would like to know if is there a software capable of generating quantitative reports (and graphics) with these FLAC files metadata. So, I could know, for example, how years, countries, or genres are distributed in my collection.

Is there something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No clue on the graphics but using the mediainfo program on the command line would do what you want. Use it in a bash script and you could process ever file you have in a loop outputting to a file of your choosing for importation into some kind of spreadsheet program, that can give you what you wish with charts and things like this in OpenOffice or whatever it is called now. I used this idea to build myself a website with all my files once upon a time, run the script and it produced the entire thing for me.

```
zeus@zeus-H370M:~$ mediainfo 38_Special-Rockin_Into_The_Night-01-Rockin_Into_The_Night.m4a | grep Track
Track name                               : Rockin' Into The Night
Track name/Position                      : 1
```